# Incoming call record not visible

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, calls, call-history

I received a call from a company and somehow my phone got discharged. When it restarted, the call record was not visible. I really need that number. Any help

Comment: Can your phone company provide the info?

Comment: @MorrisIriga i asked them but they said that you have to wait till the bill is generated.

Answer (score 1):

While your situation appears strange, you could perhaps try Android Data Recovery:

"Android Data Recovery, an incredible tool for recovering, allows you to retrieve Android data such as contacts, text messages, call history, photos, WhatsApp history, videos, audios, documents and restore them back to Android phones of any brand"

http://www.recovery-android.com/android-data-recovery.html

I've never tried that application and can't guarantee if it'll work or not.

From reading [this](http://www.recovery-android.com/recover-data-from-android.html), steps involved on recovering lost data may involve:

- stop copying data onto phone or updating to prevent overwriting data you wish to recover.
- Enable USB debugging on your Android.
- Run the Android Data Recovery and follow on screen instructions.

See link above for more details.

Comment: The link about that program you noted had been used by several spammers in the past. They all posted the same kind of answers. Consider adding the detailed steps needed to achieve the goal, so as to differentiate yourself from the spammers.

Comment: I tried many software, but didn't worked for me. Actually its not deleted.. Its just not showing that number.